# Run two shell script in parallel and capture their output

Tags: linux, shell

I want have a shell script, which configure several things and then call two other shell scripts. I want these two scripts run in parallel and I want to be able to get and print their live output.
Here is my first script which calls the other two

```
#!/bin/bash
#CONFIGURE SOME STUFF
$path/instance2_commands.sh 
$path/instance1_commands.sh
```

These two process trying to deploy two different application and each of them took around 5 minute so I want to run them in parallel and also see their live output so I know where are they with the deploying tasks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running both scripts in parallel can look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#CONFIGURE SOME STUFF
$path/instance2_commands.sh >instance2.out 2>&1 &
$path/instance1_commands.sh >instance1.out 2>&1 &
wait
```

Notes:

- `wait` pauses until the children, `instance1` and `instance2`, finish
- `2>&1` on each line redirects error messages to the relevant output file
- `&` at the end of a line causes the main script to continue running after forking, thereby producing a child that is executing that line of the script concurrently with the rest of the main script
- each script should send its output to a separate file.  Sending both to the same file will be visually messy and impossible to sort out when the instances generate similar output messages.
- you may attempt to read the output files while the scripts are running with any reader, e.g. `less instance1.out` however output may be stuck in a buffer and not up-to-date.  To fix that, the programs would have to open stdout in line buffered or unbuffered mode.  It is also up to you to use `-f` or `>` to refresh the display.

**Example D** from an [article on Apache Spark and parallel processing on my blog](http://blog.sunshineonacloudy.net/2015/06/introduction-to-apache-spark_64.html) provides a similar shell script for calculating sums of a series for Pi on all cores, given a C program for calculating the sum on one core.  This is a bit beyond the scope of the question, but I mention it in case you'd like to see a deeper example.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible, change your script to look like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #CONFIGURE SOME STUFF
    $path/instance2_commands.sh >> script.log 
    $path/instance1_commands.sh >> script.log
```

They will both output to the same file and you can watch that file by running:

```
    tail -f script.log
```

If you like you can output to 2 different files if you wish.  Just change each ling to output (>>) to a second file name.

Comment: If you want to run them in parallel, you need to put an ampersand (&) at the end, like so:  $path/instance2_commands.sh >> script.log &

Comment: Don't log them both to the same file.  There is no coordination of output.

Answer (score 0):

This how I end up writing it using Paul instruction.

```
source $path/instance2_commands.sh >instance2.out 2>&1 &
source $path/instance1_commands.sh >instance1.out 2>&1 &
tail -q -f instance1.out -f instance2.out --pid $!
wait
sudo rm instance1.out
sudo rm instance2.out
```

My logs in two processes was different so I didn't care if aren't all together, that is why I put them all in one file.